# svn: Syncing main source code with committed source code

Tags: svn

To manage my source code I have created SVN subversion server by using command

```
svnadmin create /myrepos
svn import /root/MySourceCode file:///myrepos
```

I have created user and provided rw access to him. User can easily commit their changes in repository. How can I update my sourcecode (/root/MySourceCode) used in command svn import ? Is there any svn command to update my MySourceCode with commited code?

Answer (score 2):

Having imported the source into a repo, you generally need to check out the code again from the repo version. For info try `svn help checkout`

Having done so, you will then be able to use `svn update` to take changes.

Comment: That means to update my server code I have to act like a client? and there is no way to update my /root/MySourceCode

Comment: No - think of SVN as versioned, audited storage. Regardless of the code you put in it, the SVN repo is the master store. You checkout and update from the repo, and commit your changes back into it. Have you used any SCM system before?